# sdkman hook to link /etc/ssl/java/cacerts to the currently used Java SDK

Tags: java, sdkman

Debian has a great mechanism to compile all commonly used CA certificates from Thawte, Let's Encrypt etc. as well as locally installed ones from `/usr/local/share/ssl` into one `/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` JKS file. That is usually symlinked to `$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts`.

With sdkman I switch between different non-Debian Java versions in `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/current/` which use the *cacerts* provided by the SDK creator.

Is there some kind of post-inst hook mechanism where I could automatically create a symlink to the Debian *cacerts* file whenever I switch sdkman Java versions?

Comment: If you create symlink manually, would the installation or update process override it?

Answer (score 1):

I solves this with a custom zsh function so I just have to run `sdkman cacerts ~/.cacerts` to symlink all cacerts for all sdkman installed jdks.

```
# sdkman
sdkman() {
    case $1 in
        --help)
            cat <<EOF
Alias for sdk with additional custom functions.

Usage: $0 <subcommand> [candidate] [version]

Additional Commands

    $0 --help               Print this help message
    $0 cacerts [cacerts]    Symlink all java cacerts to a custom location (default: ~/.cacerts)

EOF
            ;;
        cacerts)
            cacerts="${2:-$HOME/.cacerts}"
            if [[ -f "$cacerts" ]]; then
                for jdk in $(sdk list java | grep installed | sed 's/^.*\| \(.*\)$/\1/g'); do
                    jdkHome=$(sdk home java $jdk)
                    pushd "$jdkHome/lib/security"
                    mv cacerts cacerts.orginal
                    ln -s "$cacerts" "cacerts"
                    popd
                done
            else
                echo "Abort: file $cacerts not found."
            fi
            ;;
        *)
            sdk "$@"
    esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SDKMAN has predefined post installation hooks but there doesn't seem any way to customize them or add your own. I didn't want to create a new wrapper tool like @PeterMue because it'd cause cognitive load and also the footgun of users forgetting to run that, so my solution was to hook into the shell's prompt mechanism. I installed `starship` (https://starship.rs) and put the `eval "$(starship init <shell>)"` *below* SDKMan, and in `~/.config/starship.toml` I defined a section for a custom command which will be run during prompt generation:

```ini
[custom.java-cacerts]
when = true
shell = "sh"
command = """
set -xe
[ -f /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts ]
ALL_CACERTS=$(find -P "$SDKMAN_DIR/candidates/java" -name cacerts -type f | grep .)
echo "[java: symlinking cacerts]"
for cacerts in $ALL_CACERTS; do
  mv "$cacerts" "$cacerts.original"
  ln -s /etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts "$cacerts"
done 2>&1
"""
```

Explanation:

- `set -xe` sets the `e` flag (exit when any command errors) and the `x` flag (log commands to `stderr`)
- Since `e` flag is set, we can skip the `if` clause and write the condition at the top. If it fails, the script will short circuit
- `find -P` doesn't follow symlinks, so the `current` symlink is ignored. `-type f` to only find `cacerts` which are regular files (no symlinks)
- `find` always returns success even when no match was found. Piping that into `grep .` matches anything and causes a non-zero status when there is no input so the script will stop
- `set -x` writes everything to `stderr`, but `starship` only captures `stdout` and ignores stderr, so I use `2>&1` on the `for` loop to print those 2 commands to inform the user.

This runs very fast and on my machine the prompt delay is almost not noticeable. Also using `find` rather than a predefined path on `$JDK/lib/security/cacerts` is more backward compatible as for Java 8 the `cacerts` is under `$JDK/jre/lib/security/cacerts`.